# How to set the maximum supported iOS version in AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store, ios8

How I could notify the user of AppStore that only iOS 7.xx is supported by my application?

Is it possible to set the maximum iOS version for the application in AppStore?

The application failed on iOS 8 and I can't fix it so far...

Comment: You must fix the problem.Otherwise Apple Store will reject your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the maximum version for an app on the App Store. You can just add to the description of your app that it won't work on iOS and hope that the users look at the description. But you should really work on fixing your app for iOS 8 and release a new version of the app as soon as possible.